# Grails - References between application and local plugins

Tags: grails

I'm creating a new Grails project. I decided to split it in one application and several plugins. Now, plugins and main application need to access each others classes.

In the main application I can access plugins classes thanks to this edit in my `BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
grails.plugin.location.'plugin1' = "../Plugin1"
```

But, how can plugins access classes from the main application?

Answer (score 3):

Plugins cannot access main application. Plugins are meant to be stand alone, having no dependencies to specific main application code, but can only have dependencies to other plugins.

You need to find a way you can split your application into parts, which are independent of each other.